# DeviceClient occured timeout but message was send to IotHub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a question with `SendEventAsync()` method.

I tested insertion and removal of **LAN** cable

```
_sendDeviceClient.SetRetryPolicy(no);
_sendDeviceClient.OperationTimeoutInMillisecounds = xxx;
```

Do not retry.
Waiting xxx Millisecounds.

```
foreach() //Message1 Message2......
{  
  try
  {           
     await _sendDeviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);

     //Message send. Do success process
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     //Message failed. Do failed process 
  }
}
```

My log is "Message send", but in IotHub message was not receive message.
Sometimes, "Message failed", but Iothub received message.

I don't know why this happened.

In any case, is it a problem to implement with try & catch?

Comment: Try Catch is not an problem to implement...but its essential to know how it works and where to use it.

Comment: You are running the try/catch in a loop- are you sending multiple messages? If so, have you set up a way to tell which ones failed and which ones succeeded?

Comment: actually, there is another method out of try/catch with async. so it could recognize that failed or succeeded

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario , i am assuming you don't want to break the loop until all your message sent to respected destination. I would suggested you to use Aggregate exception which could tell you about the overall message and their status:

At the end of your loop , You can pass the List to its constructor and throw that.

At the end of your loop do:

```
AggregateException aggregateEx = new AggregateException(errors);
throw aggregateEx;
```

An application that runs on a device has to manage the mechanisms for connection, re-connection, and the retry logic for sending and receiving messages. Also, the retry strategy requirements depend heavily on the device's IoT scenario, context, capabilities.

The Azure IoT Hub device SDKs aim to simplify connecting and communicating from cloud-to-device and device-to-cloud. These SDKs provide a robust way to connect to Azure IoT Hub and a comprehensive set of options for sending and receiving messages.

Most likely , message delivery gest failed due to connection failure , which can happen at many levels.

1) Network errors: disconnected socket and name resolution errors

2) Protocol-level errors for HTTP, AMQP, and MQTT transport: detached links or expired sessions

3) Application-level errors that result from either local mistakes: invalid credentials or service behavior (for example, exceeding the quota or throttling)

The device SDKs detect errors at all three levels. OS-related errors and hardware errors are not detected and handled by the device SDKs. The SDK design is based on The [Transient Fault Handling Guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/transient-faults#general-guidelines) from the Azure Architecture Center.

I can see that you have opted for no retry policy which means you have a bandwidth or cost concerns.

Ideally one should implement proper Retry logic so that it ensure the delivery.Here you can take a look at the complete sample for [IOT HUb](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp)

you can read more about RetryGuidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific)

Hope it helps.